# How do I copy the common values from two arrays of the same length into another without duplicates?

Tags: c, arrays

In this program, I am trying to find values that are common to two arrays and then put those common values into a third array called destination. However, I am putting values from both arrays into destination, when I only want values in source1 to go into destination. How do I fix this?

```
int common_elements(int length, int source1[length], int source2[length],
                    int destination[length]) {
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  while (i < length) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < length) {
      if (source1[i] == source2[j]) {
        destination[k] = source1[i];
        k++;
      }
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return k;
}
```

Comment: "However, I am putting values from both arrays into destination, when I only want values in source1 to go into destination." Please clarify. If a value is common, it's the same in both arrays, so why does it matter from which array the value is taken?

Comment: How do you want to handle values that are present multiple times in the same array? Or are you assuming that doesn't happen?

Comment: Presumably, the values don't have to be at the same offset in both array? Just anywhere?

Comment: @dogsandcats944 Then there is also a UB in your code because you use the same `length` for iterating `source1` and `source2`.

Comment: Sorry, source1 and source2 are always meant to be the same length. So in my program so far, if source1 = [1 2 3 4 5] and source2 = [1 2 3 2 1],  then destination[k] = [1,2,3, 2,1], because source1[i] = source2[j]. However, I want destination[k] = [1,2,3], since only one 1, one 2 and one 3 is common between the two arrays.

Comment: Sorry, Mawg say reinstate Monica, I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm fairly new to coding.

Comment: So you want to find entries that have the same index AND the same value and place those into destination? Does destination have to be the same length as the two source arrays?

Comment: They don't need to have the same index, but they do need to have the same value. Destination does not need to be the same length as the two source arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the destination array to have all the elements from `source1` which are contained in `source2` (irrespective of the order of occurrence), all you need to is to add a **`break;`** statement after you increment `k` so that you break out of the inner(j) loop and continue with the next iteration of the outer(i) loop.

If source1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and source2 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

Your code will result in destination = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

If you add a break statement as suggested above, the code will result in destination = [1, 2, 3, (garbage value), (garbage value)].

To get rid of garbage values you can initialize the destination array with 0s or -1s before passing it to the method.

If you are interested in only the number of common elements, a break statement should be enough.

**Edit:**

Added the code:

```
int common_elements(int length, int source1[length], int source2[length],
                    int destination[length]) {
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  while (i < length) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < length) {
      if (source1[i] == source2[j]) {
        destination[k] = source1[i];
        k++;
        break;
      }
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return k;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if `source1` itself contains duplicates

Comment: If source1 = [1,1,1] and source2 = [1,1,2], then number of common elements in the two arrays is two and the number of unique common elements is one. @dogsandcats944 can suggest what is required.

Comment: *Re: "If source1 = [1,1,1] and source2 = [1,1,2], then number of common elements in the two arrays is two and the number of unique common elements is one."* Yes, but your algorithm will not give the correct number of *unique common elements*. At `i = 1` and `i = 2`, that `1` will be added to `destination` again.

Comment: @ArdentCoder What you are saying, I am aware of it. But OP has not mentioned anywhere that the number of unique common elements is required.

Comment: You mean, `destination = [1, 1, 1]` is the correct output, and not `destination = [1]`? *Re: "But OP has not mentioned anywhere that the number of unique common elements is required."*: Read his comments below the question.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Firstly as per my answer, the output will be `destination = [1, 1]` and not `destination = [1, 1, 1]`.

Secondly, `destination = [1, 1]` is correct common elements are required and `destination = [1]` is correct if **unique** common elements are required.

Comment: If you have time, do you mind writing out the code for how you would implement the break?

Comment: @ArdentCoder _RE: Read his comments below the question._ I have read all the comments and I do not see the word "unique" anywhere.

Comment: Yes, write the code and prove me wrong. I re-emphasise: OP wants the **unique common elements**.

Comment: @TroJaN You need not find the word **unique**, you should be able to interpret the comments: **OP does not want duplicates in the destination**.

Comment: Let's let OP speak for himself.

Comment: @TroJaN I ran your code and I was right. **Your output: `destination = [1, 1, 1]`**, whereas the expected output is `destination = [1]` for the example you gave above.

Comment: @ArdentCoder My bad for _Firstly as per my answer, the output will be `destination = [1, 1]` and not `destination = [1, 1, 1]`._

Event with `destination = [1, 1, 1]` I am going by the assumption I mentioned in my answer.

Interpretation is a subjective thing and the assumption explains how I interpreted the question. If I am wrong in understanding, OP can let me know and then I can see if I can change the answer/code.

Comment: @TroJaN, I agree with that :)

Comment: Trojan, your code works for my test arrays, but thanks to both of you for your help. :)

Comment: @dogsandcats944 Did you try his test case: `source1 = [1, 1, 1]` and `source2 = [1, 1, 2]`? If that's what you expect, then edit your question and mark this as the accepted answer to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
If you're after unique numbers that occur within both arrays.

Is this what you're after?

```
  int common_elements(int length, int source1[length], int source2[length],
                    int destination[length]) {
      int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  while (i < length) 
  {
    if (source1[i] == source2[i]) 
    {
       for (int j=0; j<k; j++)
       {
         if(destination[j] == source1[i])
            continue;
       }
       destination[k] = source1[i];
       k++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return k;
}
```

**BTW** This wont handle initialised values in the array e.g. you will see 1,2,3,0,0 in destination.

Comment: How will this work for `source1 = {1, 2, 2}` and `source2 = {3, 1, 3}`? `1` will not be added in this case.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The numbers that go into destination don't need to have the same index in source1 and source2, they just need to have the same value.

Comment: First example comment by OP suggests that is what is wanted. Now I see that the last comment contradicts this.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this problem like this:
you want to join elements of the same value in pairs, each element can only be in one pair, you want to copy value of each pair to destination array.

This will make sure values from source1 and source2 are used only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
common_elements (int length, int source1[length], int source2[length],
         int destination[length])
{
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  bool *used = malloc (sizeof (bool) * length);
  while (i < length)
    {
      int j = 0;
      while (j < length)
    {
      if (source1[i] == source2[j] && used[j] == false)
        {
          destination[k] = source1[i];
          k++;
          used[j] = true;
          break;
        }
      j++;
    }
      i++;
    }
  free(used);
  return k;
}

int
main ()
{
    int destination[3];
    int s1[] = {1,2,3};
    int s2[] = {1,1,2};
    int k = common_elements(3,s1,s2,destination);
  printf ("%d", k);

  return 0;
}
```